# How to use Phonegap in django framework for developing mobile application

Tags: cordova

i want to know whether we can use phonegap in django for developing mobile apps.i developed in adroid using phonegap.so i need a sample application program for using phonegap in django

Answer (score 1):

You can't, phonegap use only client side tecnology: html5, javascript, css.